# What quantified self products have open data behind them?

Tags: data-request, computing

Are there quantified self products (fitbit, withings, nike fuelband, zeo, etc) that share bulk aggregate data with the public via API or download? For example: runs per zipcode, steps per county, or anonymized sleep quality logs?

Comment: Some QS tools allow you to download your own data. You could setup a website where people can donate their QS data which could then be used, e.g., for research. Good care should be taken with anonymizing the data.

Answer (score 2):

There are some companies that are sharing aggregate data like the Green Button companies in energy: http://www.greenbuttondata.org/greenadopt.html but there are many of them, and it's hard to be specific without further description of the type of data you are looking for.

Some companies offer such information at an aggregate level, and others, depending on terms of service, obviously offer individualized data for a fee.

Answer (score 2):

COSM is a system that integrates the Internet of Things with open data.  There is a neat [demo](https://plus.google.com/114314928852941289704/posts/QzAdqYTqUcz) by Daniel Appelquist of W3C fame, monitoring the temperature in his living room.

*Shameless Plug*.  I am also working on an open source task management system that is linked to 100% linked open standards and read / write web called [Taskify](http://taskify.org/start).  It is currently alpha code, but I expect to announce the beta later in the year.

Answer (score 1):

The [open humans](https://www.openhumans.org/) project is all about this but each user has to opt into your analysis and I think the analysis must be done on the platform.